# Validate date so that the date cannot be in future or in past

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have this form that has a date input. What is the best way in Javascript that I can ensure the value selected is neither a future date or a past date. I have implemented jQuery date picker to select date see code below

```html
<html>
  <!--maina-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<script>
$(function() {
    var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).val();
});

function ValidateForm(){
 var date_of_circulation = document.forms["myForm"]["date_of_circulation"].value;
  if (date_of_circulation == null || date_of_circulation ==""){
   alert ("You have to select the date the manuscript was circulated");
   return false;
  }
 }
</script>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" name = "myForm" action = "" onsubmit="return ValidateForm()" method = "post">
Date of circulation:<input name="date_of_circulation" input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
<input name = "add_manuscript" type="submit" value = "submit">
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: Meaning, it has to be today?

Comment: `date cannot be in future or in past` you mean date is today??

Comment: `date cannot be in future or in past ` then what is the use of datepicker??

Comment: Not much of point having a date picker if it always has to be today. Think if you were comparing date and as detailed as seconds, you would always have to update the date picker to match the current exact timestamp. That makes no sense if the data always has to be one thing only.

Comment: My guess is this can be used as a kind of captcha, to make sure the user is human. "Please select today in the datepicker".

Comment: @all..the use of date picker is for good display

Comment: @all any suggestions that the date set cannot bein the future...meaning that the date can either be today or in the past and not the future?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this

```
var yourDate = new Date("12/5/2015"); //input value

var todayDate = new Date(); //Gets the today's date value
```

You have to use function `setHours`

```
if(yourDate.setHours(0,0,0,0) == todayDate.setHours(0,0,0,0));
{
    //Do your stuff
}
```

**NOTE:** You can also do it using the jquery's datepicker

```
var currentDate = new Date();
$("#datepicker").datepicker("setDate", currentDate);
```

so that you can be sure that today's date is already selected.

**EDIT:** You can also look at **datejs**

[datejs API Documentation](https://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation)

Comment: Thanks @identity unkown. good stuff especially datejs API Documentation

Answer (score 0):

i found an effective and simple solution by introducing maxdate and mindate as explained here: [date picker restrict date range](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max). After rethinking the validation rules i decided that the logical validation for date_of_circulation value can be a date in the past but not exceeding current date and therefore changed var date in date picker to

```html
var date = $("#datepicker").datepicker({ maxDate: new Date,dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', minDate: new Date (0) });
```

Comment: This contradicts your question where you said that the date cannot be in the past or the future. Here you are accepting any date in the past since 1st January 1970!

Answer (score -1):

If date field must be set as current date, no future or past date than
set text field's default value to current date, you need not to use date picker as it's not user friendly to have a date picker without any other date option.
Also by doing this way, you need not to validate form on submit.

```
<input name="date_of_circulation" input type="text" id="datepicker" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>" readonly="readonly">
```

set input box as readonly so that user can not change the date.

Answer (score -1):

```
userInput.max = new Date().toISOString().split("T")[0];
```

new Date(): This creates a new JavaScript Date object representing the current date and time.

.toISOString(): This converts the Date object into a string representation in the ISO 8601 format, which looks like "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.sssZ". The T separates the date and time portions.

.split("T")[0]: This splits the string at the "T" character, giving an array of substrings. [0] selects the first element of this array, which is the date portion "YYYY-MM-DD".

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).